# Using TextBlock.Text = " " is sporadically slow

Tags: wpf, vb.net, performance, textbox

I have several arrays of TextBoxes on a WPF window. I have a sub in which a For loop iterates through each of the textboxes in each of the arrays and sets the Text property to a blank space. After blanking each TextBox, it then fills them with values from a DataTable. This sub is called often, and usually the code to set the text of each TextBox (textBox.Text = "something") takes under 1ms. However, on seemingly random occasions, this line of code will take ~60ms, for each textbox in each array.

This is a huge pain, as the method is called every time the value of a scrollbar changes, and so the UI will randomly stall every second or so. I see no reason why the time taken to execute this simple piece of code should jump so dramatically for no reason?

Here is my code:

```
For X = 0 to noOfTextBoxes
  boxArray1(x).Text = " "
  boxArray2(x).Text = " "
  boxArray3(x).Text = " "
  boxArray4(x).Text = " "
Next

'textBoxes are then filled with values from a dataTable in a similar manner
```

What could cause the performance to drop so dramatically on seemingly random occasions?

Comment: how do you measure the time in ms? it should be almost unnoticable!

Comment: is that text box bound to a property that does some stuff ??

Comment: Why a 'blank space' wouldn't just a null string be OK... boxArray1(x).Text = "" or boxArray1(x).Text = String.Empty... But then I don't know if that would make a difference to the timing.

Comment: @FarhanAnam I'm stepping through it in Visual Studio. I noticed it kept halting randomly so I stepped in and found out that mostly the code only took 1ms, but sometimes it would just randomly take around 60ms. As it's in a for loop, it's adding up to around 2-3 seconds.

Comment: @Muds No it's not bound, I'm just setting it using textBox.Text = "something"

Comment: @Mych I already tried setting it to String.Empty and it made no difference.

Comment: Without knowing your specifics it seams strange to me that you are clearing textboxes and then populating them. Could you not just populate them? You have said you have no timing issue with this. Any bind that is null would/should set the textbox value to an empty string.